# Loading a custom block into Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, xml

Magento is still very much a learning curve for myself but I'm trying to steer away from so much of my hard-coded, procedural PHP and start following the Magento MVC. I've set myself the task of converting a singular .phtml file that I've created a best-sellers carousel for into an extension that follows the proper MVC. Here's my code/files:

**app/code/local/Liam/Interested/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <modules>
        <liam_interested>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </liam_interested>
    </modules>
    <blocks>
        <interested>
            <rewrite>
                <interested>Liam_Interested_Block_Interested</interested>
            </rewrite>
        </interested>
    </blocks>

</global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Liam/Interested/Block.php:**

```
<?php
class Liam_Interested_Block_Interested extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // necessary methods
}
?>
```

**app/etc/modules/Liam_Interested.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Liam_Interested>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Liam_Interested>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/custom/default/template/interested/interested.phtml:**

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

Then, in my **CMS** - I'm adding:

```
{{block type="interested/interested" name="interested_interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"}}
```

This was based on following a guide online, but I still can't seem to get my head around it all!

Answer (score 0):

You should change `app/code/local/Liam/Interested/etc/config.xml` file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
         <liam_interested>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
         </liam_interested>
      </modules>
      <global>
         <blocks>
           <interested>
              <class>Liam_Interested_Block_Interested</class>
           </interested>
         </blocks>
      </global>
   </config>
```

Comment: I tried the above but my block still doesn't appear to be displaying my test content.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define block class

```
<blocks>
        <interested>
                <class>Liam_Interested_Block</class>
        </interested>
    </blocks>
```

you can call block in xml

```
<block type="interested/interested" name="interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me I'm afraid. Struggling to work out why it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1** app/etc/modules/Liam_Interested.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Liam_Interested>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Liam_Interested>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step : 2** app/code/local/Liam/Interested/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Liam_Interested>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Liam_Interested>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <interested>
                <class>Liam_Interested_Block_Interested</class>
            </interested>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step : 3** app/code/local/Liam/Interested/Block.php:

```
<?php
class Liam_Interested_Block_Interested extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // necessary methods
}
?>
```

**Step : 4** app/design/frontend/custom/default/template/interested/interested.phtml:

```
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

**Step : 5** In CMS Page- :

```
{{block type="interested/interested" name="interested_interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Hi @Abdul - I tried all of the above but my block is still empty :(

Comment: if you try code in cms page then content display or not 

Code Is : {{block type="core/text_list" name="interested" as="interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"}}

Comment: Still nothing. Struggling to get my head around it and there doesn't seem to be that many tutorials on the Internet to achieve something as basic as this!

Comment: can you share screen shot to added cms page?

Comment: You are going wrong way in admin side cms page

Comment: http://imgur.com/WPibHR8

Answer (score 0):

You haven't required **rewrite** tag in your config.xml file.

Proper code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <modules>
        <liam_interested>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </liam_interested>
    </modules>
    <blocks>
        <interested>
                <interested>Liam_Interested_Block</interested>
        </interested>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Add in cms below code:

```
{{block type="interested/interested" name="interested_interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"}}
```

1. Tag  **rewrite** is useful when you have to change Core block functionality. You can check more info for overriding block from here. http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/