# Custom Block on Home Page

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, blocks

Earlier on, I asked this question:
[Loading a custom block into Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90759/loading-a-custom-block-into-magento) but I still couldn't work out what was wrong.

I've just now noticed that if I add:

```
<block type="interested/interested" name="interested" as="interested" template="interested/interested.phtml">
```

to my catalog.xml file and inside my product view.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('interested');?>
```

I now see my extension working as it should, so the question is, why isn't it possible to load my extension into the home page via CMS using:

```
{{block type="interested/interested" name="interested" as="interested" template="interested/interested.phtml"}}
```

Does the CMS have restrictions on loading custom extensions or is there more that I have to specify in my core/local files?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but have you tried removing `name="interested" as="interested"`?

Comment: Might also help if you can share the code from the block file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest security patch as of this writing, you need to whitelist this Block for use in the cms in `System > Permissions > Blocks`. Adding it in the table there should allow you to use it in cms